# python csv headers not in first line

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file deliminated by `,`.
The first line contains the report name, the second line contains the report data.
The headers are in line 3 and all the other rows are data.
How do I use the csv module to read the headers from line 3 instead of 1?
Below is what I have now.

```
import csv
f = open ("myfile.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
headers = reader.next()
```

Comment: Call `reader.next()` or `next(reader)` 3 times!

Comment: @falsetru is right.  The `csv` module doesn't check that all rows are the same, so you can just call `next()` to consume them and throw them away.

Comment: Actually, if you want the data from the extra lines, you can just read it in a line at time (and save it, if desired) and then create the `csv.reader` object. The current position of the file doesn't have to at its very beginning when you do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to discard items from an iterator.

```
from itertools import islice
reader = islice(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","), 2, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not very large, you can just read everything and discard the first two lines later:

```
with file("myfile.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    lines = list(reader)[2:]
headers, value_rows = lines[0], lines[1:]
for row in value_rows:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could iterate until you get the desired line:

```
import csv
headerLine = 3
f = open ("myfile.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
for ii in range(0, headerLine):
    headers = reader.next()
```